# Exception using HttpRequest.execute(): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

Tags: java, httpclient, google-api-java-client

I'm using google-api-client-java 1.2.1-alpha to execute a POST request, and am getting the following stacktrace when I execute() the HttpRequest.

It happens immediately after I catch and ignore a 403 error from a previous POST to the same URL, and re-used the transport for the subsequent request.  (It's in a loop inserting multiple entries to the same ATOM feed).

Is there something I should be doing to 'clean up' after a 403?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at com.google.api.client.apache.ApacheHttpRequest.execute(ApacheHttpRequest.java:47)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:207)
    at au.com.machaira.pss.gape.RedirectHandler.execute(RedirectHandler.java:38)
    at au.com.machaira.pss.gape.ss.model.records.TableEntry.executeModification(TableEntry.java:81)
```

Why would the code below me be trying to acquire a *new* connection?

Comment: This still seems to be an issue with version 1.11.0-beta :/

Comment: For the benefit of anyone arriving here after trying to consume the responses and still getting the warnings - I found the correct answer here: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/05/05/fixing-the-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-connection-still-allocated-problem/

Comment: @Steelight - using the [tech.chitgoks.com](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/05/05/fixing-the-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-connection-still-allocated-problem/) approach resolved my issue.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to consume the response body before you can reuse the connection for another request. You should not only read the response status, but read the response `InputStream` fully to the last byte whereby you just ignore the read bytes.

Comment: That was it!  In the case of `google-api-java-client`, this meant catching the `IOException` thrown by `HttpResponse.execute()`, testing/casting it to `HttpResponseException`, accessing the `response` member, and then invoking `paraseAsString()` on it. (Which turned out to be useful information anyhow :- )

Comment: There is also a HttpEntity.consumeContent() method to discard the content.

Comment: EntityUtils.consume(entity) - consumeContent is now deprecated.

Comment: Just to note that as of recent versions of Google Http Java Client (at least 1.16, but possibly earlier), calling `HttpRequest.execute()` will automatically clean up these resources if the method fails to return a `HttpResponse` object.  Further, the JavaDoc of `HttpResponse` now recommends calling `response.disconnect()` in case of not fully reading the content of the HTTP response (in a `finally` block).

Comment: Same problem with RestEasy 3.0.4 which internally uses BasicClientConnectionManager of apache-httpclient 4.2.1. Thank You @BalusC. Also I never read anything about reading the stream fully, where should one look at when it comes to be aware of these pitfalls ? (documentation-wise, other than source code)

Comment: @dashboard: I've also never seen it documented anywhere. I guess that's what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 42):

I was facing a similar issue when using the HttpClient with Jetty to build a test framework. I had to create multiple requests to the Servelet from my client, but It was giving the same exception when executed.

I found an alternative at http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/http-connections-revisited.html

You can also use this following method to instantiate your client.

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient()  {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, 

            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked pretty good. However I'm curious on the necessity to create two DefaultHttpClients

Comment: He uses default HttpParams (gets them from client) instead of creating own from scratch.

Comment: That solved my problem, but is it ok to use this in android application.

Comment: Interestingly, that partially works for me, ends up blocking the remaining code from executing when I make several HTTP requests in a loop and not consume the responses. And no failure either, I didn't wait too long to see if a timeout error occurs though. So instead I went the route of allocating new DefaultHttpClients for each request and that worked for me, since I don't run the loop very long.

Answer (score 9):

A similar exception message (since at least Apache Jarkata Commons HTTP Client 4.2) is:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.`

This exception can happen when two or more threads interact with a single `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`.

How can you make a 4.2 `DefaultHttpClient` instance threadsafe (*threadsafe* in the sense that two or more threads can interact with it without getting above error message)? Provide `DefaultHttpClient` with a connection-pooling `ClientConnectionManager` in the form of `org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager`!

```
/* using
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
*/

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

public class MyComponent {

    private HttpClient client;

    {
        PoolingClientConnectionManager conMan = new PoolingClientConnectionManager( SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault() );
        conMan.setMaxTotal(200);
        conMan.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient(conMan);

        //The following parameter configurations are not
        //neccessary for this example, but they show how
        //to further tweak the HttpClient
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 20000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 15000);
    }


    //This method can be called concurrently by several threads
    private InputStream getResource(String uri) {
        try {
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(uri);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(method);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            InputStream is = null;
            if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == statusCode) {
                logger.debug("200 OK Amazon request");
                is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            } else {
                logger.debug("Something went wrong, statusCode is {}",
                        statusCode);
                 EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
            }
            return is;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Something went terribly wrong", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an often-asked question.  BalusC's response is correct.  Please catch [HttpReponseException](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException.html), and call HttpResponseException.[response](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException.html#response).[ignore](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse.html#ignore())().  If you need to read the error message, use response.[parseAsString](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse.html#parseAsString())() if you don't know the response content type, else if you do know the content type use response.[parseAs](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.2-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse.html#parseAs(java.lang.Class))(MyType.class).

A simple code snippet from [YouTubeSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/youtube-jsonc-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/youtube/YouTubeSample.java?repo=samples) in [youtube-jsonc-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/youtube-jsonc-sample/instructions.html?r=default) (though usually you'll want to do something smarter in a real application):

```
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    System.err.println(e.response.parseAsString());
  }
```

Full disclosure: I am an owner of the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) project.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that this is an often-asked question suggest that there is a usability problem in your library design?

Comment: @sanity Or maybe in the http stack itself ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a jax-rs (resteasy) `Response` object in my unit tests.
I solved this with a call to `response.releaseConnection();`
The releaseConnection()-Method is only on the resteasy `ClientResponse` object, so I had to add a cast from `Response` to `ClientResponse`.

Comment: That saved my day! In my case I had to cast to org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse to further narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpGet);
response.getEntity().consumeContent();
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) {
        //task
    Log.i("Connection", "OK");
    }else{
     Log.i("Connection", "Down");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have similar problem, all those solution not work, i tested on some device, problem was date in device, it was 2011 instead 2013, check also this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Read the InputStream like this:

```
if( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 ) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    try {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( content ), 8 );
        String line;
        while( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
            sb.append( line );
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        content.close();
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        Log.e( "statusCode", ex.getMessage() + "" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just consume the response like below, that will solve the issue

```
response.getEntity().consumeContent();
```