# How to release or know if a http client is free in android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I get this exception when my app user tries to get data from a web server using a client which is already doing some other work in the background.

I am using the same client throughout the application to maintain session.

The exception suggests :

```
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

How to release it? Or it would be better if i can check whether its free of not. So that i can wait until it gets free or release

Thank You

Comment: I think this is usefull [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection)