# Apache Http Client in Android

Tags: java, android, html, apache, http

I'm trying to get the whole html from a web page in Android.

In java console aplication I used to do like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String busca = "kindle";        
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+busca);
try {
    ResponseHandler<String> manipulador = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String resposta = httpclient.execute(httpGet,manipulador);
    }

} finally {
    httpGet.releaseConnection();
}
```

I tried to do the same in my Android aplication but I didn't work!

This library works in Android?

```
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Is there in better way to get a page html code in a string on Android?

Thks for the help!

Comment: Exactly what happens?  Post your logs or the HTTP response coming back from the server.

Comment: Fisrt of all, the code in "finally" was showing me an erro, so I erased it and put 

    catch (Exception e) {
             return e.getMessage().toString();
            }

int its place.

Now it doesn't give me any error. But I tried to show the string resposta (who should have the whole HTML) in a textView, but it comes blank!

In debug mode I can see the code in my "try" isn't working. It throws an exception..

Comment: Edit the question to include details of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with another URl and it worked :)

Maybe the HTML code of that page I was using as to big to save in a String or to show in a Text

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loot at this :
   [HttpClient 4.0.1 - how to release connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection)

HttpRequestBase.releaseConnection() is introduced in Version 4.2