# Should we not be closing the connection after response in JestHttpClient for elastic search

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, elasticsearch-jest

This is with respect to the code at 
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/main/java/io/searchbox/client/http/JestHttpClient.java

In this code snippet

```
public <T extends JestResult> T execute(Action<T> clientRequest) throws IOException {
    HttpUriRequest request = prepareRequest(clientRequest);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    return deserializeResponse(response, request, clientRequest);
}

private <T extends JestResult> T deserializeResponse(HttpResponse response, Action<T> clientRequest) throws IOException {
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    return clientRequest.createNewElasticSearchResult(
            response.getEntity() == null ? null : EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()),
            statusLine.getStatusCode(),
            statusLine.getReasonPhrase(),
            gson
    );
}
```

After we receive the response should we not be doing something like

```
response.close()
```

This particular stack overflow thread [HttpClient 4.0.1 - how to release connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection) mentions about consuming the response entity using

```
EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity)
```

Would just doing `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` suffice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` will suffice if it can finish successfully. If an UnsupportedEncodingException is throw for instance, the response will not be read by `toString` and connection will be blocked. My suggestion is to call `EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity)` in `finally` block to prevent hanging connections.