# Android get image from url SingleClientConnManager problem

Tags: android, arrays, httpresponse, http-error

I am using following code to get the images of a logo and save it in the database.

```
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet mHttpGet;
HttpResponse mHttpResponse;
HttpEntity entity;


for (int reportsCount = 0; reportsCount < reportsArr.length; reportsCount++) {



  //Make a request to get our image
  mHttpGet = new HttpGet(reportsArr[reportsCount][1]);
  byte[] categoryLogoArr = null; 
  try {
    mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);

    if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {


       entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();

       logoArr= EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

    }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   long categoryID = dataHelper.addCategory(reportsArr[reportsCount][0], categoryLogoArr);
}
```

The first image added perfectly, but rest of the cases it is not working and giving the following warning.

```
WARN/SingleClientConnManager(2389): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
```

What is problem in my code? What to change to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consume the content before you can reuse the connection. This may be a duplicate of [Exception using HttpRequest.execute(): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612573/exception-using-httprequest-execute-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-co)

I think that you need to consume the content even if the response code is not HttpStatus.SC_OK, and in your exception handlers.

Comment: but i failed to add catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.response.parseAsString();
    }...it is giving "e.response cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: According to the javadocs for the Android version of HttpClient, HttpResponseException does not support a "response" member, so you should not be trying to access it. Just ensure that you call entity.consumeContent() for all possible scenarios.

Comment: I used  if (entity != null)
            entity.consumeContent();

          mHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); and it works perfectly.