# Releasing connection of HttpClient 4.1.x for sequential execution with one HttpClient instance

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm sorry for a little duplication, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4775618/306488), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4612573/306488), but they say, that if you read the the last byte of the body of response and close the input stream. It is ready for another request. But look what I got here, and I always get this error when executing a new request.

> Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

```
public String detectGooglePost(String text) throws SystemException {

        List<NameValuePair> qParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        qParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));

        List<NameValuePair> bodyParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        bodyParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", text));

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(createURI(qParams));
        httpPost.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(bodyParams));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new SystemException("Problem when buidling Google request entity", e);
        }

        String language = getLanguage(httpPost);
        return language;
    }

    private String getLanguage(HttpUriRequest request) throws SystemException {

        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException("Problem when executing Google request", e);
        }

        int sc = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (sc != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            throw new SystemException("google status code : " + sc);

        StringBuilder builder = getBuilder(response);
        String language = processJson(builder.toString());

        return language;
    }

    private StringBuilder getBuilder(HttpResponse response) throws SystemException {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity == null)
            throw new SystemException("response entity null");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String str;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                builder.append(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SystemException("Reading input stream of http google response entity problem", e);
        } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
        if (builder.length() == 0)
            throw new SystemException("content stream of response entity empty has zero length");
        return builder;
    }
```

How should I release the connection ? The stream is read and closed. But still when detectGooglePost(text) method is called again (singleton HttpClient instance), it throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man it must work, try this :

```
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseBody;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        int sc = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (sc != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            throw new SystemException("google status code : " + sc);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity == null)
            throw new SystemException("response entity null");
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        request.abort();
        throw new SystemException("Problem when executing Google request", e);
    }
```