# Android: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

Tags: java, android, httpclient, httpconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception using HttpRequest.execute(): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612573/exception-using-httprequest-execute-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-c)

I am working in Android. I created HttpSingleton class to create single intance of HttpClient in my complete application.

This is my code to use this class:-

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("url/dologin/savitagupta/savitagupta");
**HttpResponse rp = HttpSigleton.getInstance().execute(get);**          
if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
   // some code here
}
```

and this is my class for single instance

```
public class HttpSigleton {
  private static HttpClient instance = null;
  protected HttpSigleton() {

  }
  public static HttpClient getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
       instance =new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    return instance;
 }
}
```

Then error is occurred is :-

SingleClientConnManager : Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
 Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
Please suggest me what mistake i have done. I really need your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After calling:

```
HttpResponse rp = HttpSigleton.getInstance().execute(get);
```

Please make sure you make a call to either:

```
String html = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity() /*, Encoding */);
```

or

```
EntityUtils.consume(rp.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 28):

For Android:

If you are not interested in the content, the cheapest way to get rid of your connection and avoid the error "connection still allocated" is:

```
httpResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#consumeContent()