# Error in Android using SingleClientConnManager

Tags: java, php, android, sql, android-asynctask

I'm currently trying to learn a bit about AsyncTask'ing in Android. I'm using a code fragment of some school project im working with, but I can't seem to run it properly. The error I am getting is the following:

**"Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one."**

So basicly I do understand *what* it says, that I need to close the http-connection before I start another one. (Correct me if I'm wrong lol) So I'm wondering if someone could please help me out here as I've been stuck for several hours.

The code I am using is the following:

```
protected class loader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("url_of_my_phpdocument_here.php");
            //legg til data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //tv.setText(""+response);
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
            {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.obligatorisk.BROWSER"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I did alot of research and I found solutions, but they seem to be very different and custom for those examples I found. Even tho I've been messing around with them for very long I can't seem to make any of them work.

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager occurs in Android 2.2,2.3 but not in 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554081/invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-occurs-in-android-2-2-2-3-but-not-in-4-1)

you may want to look at the thread-safe issues mentioned above. I think u need to be aware of whether your API version defaults to single thread or not in the 'async-task'.